# Why does this command not create a log?

Tags: linux, bash

Why does the following not create a log?

```sh
#Create a file if log not detected

ssh root@MYSERVERIP [ ! -f "/tmp/73793.log]" then date > /tmp/FileNotExist fi
```

Comment: Are you trying to create the log file on the remote or the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your "if... then ... fi" is not complete. You can write it that way:

```
ssh root@MYSERVERIP ; 
if [ ! -f "/tmp/73793.log" ] ; then date > /tmp/FileNotExist ; fi
```

or you could write it without "if then fi" (but then you should not write then and fi). It can be written that way:

```
ssh root@MYSERVERIP ; 
[ -f "/tmp/73793.log" ] || date > /tmp/FileNotExist
```

Comment: I think he wants the commands executed on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Spacing and quoting can confuse the parser when executing commands remotely via ssh.
Try this:

```
ssh $usr@$MYSERVERIP 'set -x; if [ -f /tmp/73793.log ]; then ls -l some.log; else date>/tmp/FileNotExist; fi'
```

or

```
ssh "$usr@$MYSERVERIP" 'if [ ! -f /tmp/73793.log ]; then date>/tmp/FileNotExist; fi'
```

MYSERVERIP is a funny name for a server, so I assumed it's a variable and added a `$`, and used `$usr` too. Adjust as required.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of proper quoting and it works with your original idea:

```
ssh root@MYSERVERIP 'if [ ! -f /tmp/73793.log ] ; then date > /tmp/FileNotExist ; fi'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys so much

This worked:

ssh "$usr@$MYSERVERIP" 'if [ ! -f /tmp/73793.log ]; then date>/tmp/FileNotExist; fi'